# Data of another column appears into another row when displayed in table

Tags: php, html, mysql

What I'm trying to do is to display owners data including its members in a table. However someone's data appears in another row where should not be. Here is my table structure for members table:

```
+-----------+---------+------------+
| unitMemId | ownerId | members    |
+-----------+---------+------------+
|         1 |       1 | bato       |
|         2 |       1 | manpacq    |
|         3 |       1 | allan      |
|         4 |       2 | hontiveros |
|         5 |       2 | kitty      |
|         6 |       3 | jinky      |
|         7 |       3 | sandara    |
+-----------+---------+------------+
```

As you could observe, the `ownerid` column owns data `bato`, `manpacq` and `allan`, but when it is displayed into table it appears like this:

```
 First Name   Middle Name  Lastname    Members   Unit No.   UnitSqmtrs

   Rody          Roa        Duterte    bato        205         150
   Sarah         Null       Duterte    manpacq     111         200
   Manny         Pacman     Pacquiao   allan       203         300
   Titto         Yow        Sotto      Hontiveros  404         5585
```

Data `manpacq` and `allan` appears into row `Sarah` when it should appear into `Rody`, I tried adding a column to my table but the same process goes on. Here is my table in html:

```
 echo '<section class="">
 <div class="container">
   <table>
     <thead>
      <tr class="header">
        <th>
          First Name
          <div>First Name</div>
        </th>
        <th>
          Middle Name
          <div>Middle Name</div>
        </th>
        <th>
          Lastname
          <div>Lastname</div>
        </th>
       <th>
          Members
          <div>Members</div>
        </th>
        <th>
          Unit No.
          <div>Unit No.</div>
        </th>
        <th>
         Unit Squaremeters
          <div>Unit Squaremeters</div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>';
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['middlename'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['members'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['unitNo'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['squareMtrs'] . "</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
      }
      echo "</table>";
      echo "</div>";
      echo "</section>";
```

Hope my structure for posting a question is acceptable.

Comment: can you show us the sql join you're doing? where comes that "Rody/Sarah" info? wich is the ON column between the tables?

Comment: Please include your sql. So that we can help you better

Comment: Oh sure `SELECT owner.firstname, owner.middlename, owner.lastname, ownerdetails.cpno, unitmembers.members, unitowner.unitNo, unitowner.squareMtrs
FROM unitowner INNER JOIN (unitmembers INNER JOIN (ownerlogindetails INNER JOIN (ownerdetails INNER JOIN owner ON ownerdetails.ownerDetId = owner.ownerId) ON ownerlogindetails.ownerLogDetId = owner.ownerId) ON unitmembers.unitMemId = owner.ownerId) ON unitowner.unitOwnId = owner.ownerId`